# Passing Variable from Node.js Server to Client

Tags: node.js

On my node.js server I have the following code:

```
//Generate a token
var token = capability.generateToken();

//Serve the page
var html = fs.readFileSync('learn.htm').toString();
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
response.end(html);
}
```

Now on the client side (in learn.htm) I want to access the token variable.  My question is, how do I pass the variable to the client in the response? There must be a simple way of doing this but I'm struggling to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send some JavaScript to the client which sets the variable. Or you could store it in a `data-` attribute e.g. of the body tag (`<body data-token="...">`) and then access it via `$('body').data('token')` in case you have jQuery on the client side.

If you need it for a form you can also store it in a hidden input field.

Comment: How would I append the data attribute to the body tag? On the client I would use jquery but I'm not sure how I would do this from server-side.

Comment: You need to use some kind of template engine; right now you only read a static file without any proper way to substitute values inside it.

Comment: OK.  I was trying to hold off on learning a template engine until I become better versed in node by itself.  Perhaps this is just one of those use-cases where a template engine is absolutely required.

Comment: You have a plain string so you can always `.replace('{TOKEN}', token)` and then put `{TOKEN}` in your HTML file. For a single value that's actually fine, but if you need more, better use a template engine.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using a template language for your HTML. There are several available, just search for node.js template language or using npm:

```
npm search templates
```

**Edit:** Some popular ones are [jade](http://jade-lang.com/), [ejs](http://embeddedjs.com/), [hogan.js](http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/).

Comment: [{{ Mustache }} Templating](http://mustache.github.com/) is the easiest and most intuitive to learn for a beginner IMO

Answer (score 0):

Put something like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{TOKEN}}">
```

in your HTML, then replace the {{TOKEN}} string with the token at each request.

Then use JS like:

```
var token = $("input#csrf_token").val();
```

to get the value in your client script.

Edit: I haven't used it myself, but nowjs (http://nowjs.com/) is a more general way of getting your server's variables to the client. It's probably not what you want for passing a simple token, but it might be of interest.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer works as well.  +1 for the nowjs tip.  I'll check it out.